# Efficient where clause on field that has json

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2019

I have the following query that i would like to add a where clause on a json field,
Below is my json I filter out based on a list of categories, in below example, there is 3 categories and if i pass in 7,9, I want the below record to be included in my list.

I guess I am not sure what my where clause for json would look like and be effecient

TSql

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM Tweets                                
  WHERE IsProcessed = 0 AND HasEvents = 1
  AND --Json filter
  ORDER BY TweetDate DESC
```

Json

```
{
   "Dates":{
      "DateTimeResults":[
         {
            "DateTime":"2014-03-20T00:00:00-04:00",
            "UtcOffsetMinutes":0,
            "Text":"today",
            "Timex":"2014-03-20"
         }
      ]
   },
   "Categories":[
      7,
      9,
      12
   ]
}
```

Comment: You'll wanna use a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data?view=sql-server-ver15) to persist the JSON data you wanna search on.

Comment: @ErikDarling thank you, ya i figured I will need a index but what would the actual query be to filter out "Categories"?

Comment: Index <> computed column but a combination of both will allow efficient querying against your JSON column. The computed column would store the logic to structure your JSON column in a more *normalized* format. But to determine what format to structure it in depends on the question of what does "*if i pass in 7,9*" mean?...in other words, are you saying the `Categories` field has to contain both 7 and 9?

Comment: @J.D. thank you i thought they are the same, (not a dba here), categories contains a list of ids as shown in the example, and essentially when comparing I would be comparing the filter against this, above has 3 categiries, 7, 9 and 12, if i say give me all records with category 7 and 9, the above will be returned as it contains those two and more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
use tempdb
go
create table Tweets(Message nvarchar(1024), IsProcessed bit, HasEvents bit, Details nvarchar(max))

insert into Tweets(Message,IsProcessed,HasEvents,Details)
            values ('foo',0,1,N'
            {
   "Dates":{
      "DateTimeResults":[
         {
            "DateTime":"2014-03-20T00:00:00-04:00",
            "UtcOffsetMinutes":0,
            "Text":"today",
            "Timex":"2014-03-20"
         }
      ]
   },
   "Categories":[
      7,
      9,
      12
   ]
}')

go

declare @categories nvarchar(max) = '[7,9]'

select *
from Tweets t
where (select count(distinct value) from openjson(@categories) ) =
      (
       select count(distinct value) 
       from  openjson (t.Details, '$.Categories')  c
       join openjson(@categories) rc
        on c.value = rc.value 
       )
```

You *could* persist the Categories as a computed column like this:

```
create table Tweets
(
  Message nvarchar(1024), 
  IsProcessed bit, 
  HasEvents bit, 
  Details nvarchar(max), 
  Categories as json_query(Details,'$.Categories') persisted
)
```

But I'm not sure that would be meaningfully more efficient.

Comment: exactly what i am looking for thank you, on a side node, what should my computed field on the "details"  (AnalyzedResults) field should be to make this query as performant as possible.

Comment: I followed your idea of computed field on the categories but it didnt seem to improve much when the table has 1M records, tried creating a index on the computed field but couldnt as its using json_query (i think).

Comment: Yep.  You would have to extract the categories to a separate table TweetCategories(TweetId,CategoryId) for indexing to help and to avoid runtime JSON parsing.

Comment: thanks for the heads up on that, that was my backup option and it seems like going to that is the logical option, thank you for all your help